# AWS public IPv4 in userdata script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sed, ipv4

I need to dynamically discover the ip4v address of my instance (during userdata script execution and use it to replace some XML. I've tried the following but it doesn't work. Presumably because networking isn't available at the time we the instance runs the userdata script?

Also, to add complexity, assume this instance has no external internet access (so other solutions suggesting `curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com/` won't work).

`sudo sed -i -e "s,<listenaddress address=\",<listenaddress address=\"$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4),g" /tmp/my.config.xml`

I'm using the default Amazon AMI (Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-ed100689)

Any ideas?

Edit: Full userdata script

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script starts a extra small service with 512MB heap.
# USE ONLY FOR DEMOS
sudo useradd myuser
sudo groupadd myuser
sudo usermod -a -G myuser myuser
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk wget -y
sudo wget https://files.mysite.com/downloads/service/whatever.jar -P /opt
sudo /usr/bin/java8 -jar /opt/whatever.jar -b 64 -t /opt/software
sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /opt/software
sudo cp /opt/software/init.d/serviceFile /etc/init.d

# Other SED commands on /etc/init.d/serviceFile which ARE working

sudo chkconfig --add /etc/init.d/serviceFile

# Start service to generate XML config file
sudo service serviceFile start

# Stop service to release file locks
sudo service serviceFile stop

# Lookup IP and do replacement <-- Problem here 
sudo sed -i -e "s,<listenaddress address=\",<listenaddress address=\"$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4),g" /opt/software/conf/collector.config.xml

# Restart service
sudo service serviceFile start
```

Comment: what exactly `doesn't work` mean? What is the output and what are you expecting?

Comment: The sed command doesn't replace anything eg. `<listenaddress address=""` remains as-is. I'm expecting `<listenaddress address="123.45.67.891"` ... It works when the machine in up and running and I execute this via putty

Comment: This looks like configuration for a listen socket... you don't bind your socket listeners to the public IPv4 address in EC2.  You always bind to the **private** address.  The Internet Gateway *always* translates the public IP outside to the private IP inside, via static 1:1 NAT, which is automatically provisioned.  Instances do not see their external IP address on their IP stack.  (Not to mention, in most applications, binding to `0.0.0.0` is sufficient.)

Answer (score 5):

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

You can fetch a bunch of data about current instance from this ip

[image]

[image: /var/log/cloud-init-output.log]

Answer (score 0):

It is likely `/tmp/my.config.xml` is created after the execution of the script. Remember everything in `/tmp` is wiped out when an instance is launched.

I tried it with `/home/ec2-user/my.config.xml` and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, the actual path is `/opt/mysoftware/whatever/my.config.xml`
The full userdata script actually downloads and installs a piece of software then calls sed on some files (this bit is working). It then starts the service (the XML file we're talking about is dynamically created at first run of service). I shutdown the service and _then_ try to do this sed

Comment: Add `echo \`wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4\` > /tmp/test` and check if `/tmp/test` has the ip address. This rules out if the metadata is available at that time.

Comment: Looks like I need to wait between `service start` and `service ... stop`. The sevice isn't starting fully before it's shutting down. There's a `service ... status` but I'm not good enough to know how to do an if statement... I'll have a play